# How to use google drive file list api with drive API Key without oAuth2.0?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer

How we can use google drive list file API "GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files" using google drive API key and without using Google OAuth2.0

Comment: You can use drive.files.list using API key like ``https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?key={YOUR_API_KEY}``. But there are things it can do and things it can't. For example, the file list cannot be directly retrieved using the API key, and if you want to retrieve a file list in a folder, you can retrieve it using ``https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?key={YOUR_API_KEY}&q='folderId'+in+parents``. In this case, the folder is required to be shared. If this information was not useful for your situation, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

API keys are not sufficient for your goal. API keys are solely for *authorization* (ie. "you may make this API call"), they cannot do *authentication* (ie. "you are yourname@gmail.com"). Without authentication, you're trying to ask this API method "show me all files which match my search" and it is rejecting your request because there can't be any files which match that search for everyone (since files are organized in accounts).

OAuth 2.0 does both *authorization* (identifies your Google Cloud project as having enabled this API) and *authentication* (identifies your end-user account, with your permission, so it knows who is making the call), so the API knows what files belong to you and thus what results to return.

As such, the Google Drive API requires OAuth 2.0 authorization ([see here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth)).

Comment: I'm able to go to https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=%27{my folder ID}%27+in+parents&key={my API key} and it displays all files in that folder, see here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54666261/node-js-how-to-get-content-of-google-drive-api-in-the-fastest-way-possible

Comment: @bluejayke how did you manage to access files in drive ? how did you get permissions ?